# Compare dictionaries Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I want to compare two dictionaries. I want to check if the key are the same, then compare the values and return the key + the dictionary name with the highest value

```
dicts1 = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}
dicts2 = {'a':7, 'b':1, 'c':4}
```

Should return:

```
dictsNew = {'a':"dicts2", 'b':"dicts1", 'c':"dicts2"}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: So what should happen if the two dictionaries have different keys?

Comment: the way they're created, they would always have the same keys @timgeb

Comment: In that case, see the answer by Adem Öztaş in the duplicate question.